# Uploading files using Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on button Upload completed form, through selenium using XPath, however this does not do anything with its XPath, I was wondering if anyone had any suggested answers?

[image]

Below is the HTML from inspecting Chrome.

```
<button ng-if="$root.AccessLevel.Standard" class="btn btn--small btn--icon ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="vm.uploads[workCategory.Id].reference" ngf-max-size="'5MB'" ngf-model-invalid="vm.uploads[workCategory.Id].referenceInvalid" ngf-pattern="'.pdf,.doc,.docx,.bmp,.gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.tif,.wmf,.png'" ngf-select="vm.uploadFile($file, 'WorkCategoryReference', workCategory.Id, workCategory.References, workCategory.Id+'uploadRef')">
    <span promise="vm.promises[workCategory.Id+'uploadRef']">
        <span ng-hide="pending" class="">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="pending" class="ng-hide">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
        </span>
    </span>
    Upload completed form
</button>
```

Below is my NUnit class with the XPath passed in

```
wait.PathWaitAndClick(driver, "*[@id=\"accordiongroup - 299 - 4516 - panel\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot/tr/td/button", 2000);
```

Also below I’m using WebExtension method.

```
public static void PathWaitAndClick(this WebDriverWait wait, IWebDriver driver, string path, int pause = 0)
{
    if (pause > 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pause);
    }
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(path)));
    IWebElement viewAllWc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path));
    if (pause > 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pause);
    }
    viewAllWc.Click();
}
```

Comment: Three simple questions: Is your xpath valid athe the clicking moment? Is the button inside a iframe tag? Can you pause your running method and check if some error is throwed at browser console?

Comment: It does not, hit my break point @StriterAlfa

Comment: You can check if your xpath is valid using the command $x("your xpath") at the chrome console. You can also check if it is inside an iframe checking the page's html. If the debugger can't reach your breakpoint to debug your clicking action, there is something wrong that is not what you are asking for help

Comment: @StriterAlfa the error I get is   wait.PathWaitAndClick(driver, "*[@id=\"accordiongroup-299-451-panel\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot/tr/td/button", 2000) Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. void

Comment: I know that the error is in that line, but have you tested the xpath as i said? have you checked if that element is inside an iframe? there are some error in browser console? all these points can impact and result on a error in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited context of HTML you've provided, I would utilize `contains` in your XPath to search for given `button` element containing the string `"Upload completed form"`.

```
//button[contains(., 'Upload completed form')]
```